# Loading BootstrapDialog with RequireJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, bootstrap-dialog

I am trying to load BootstrapDialog http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ with requireJS but so far I am unsuccessful as it is always null.

This is my current configuration:

```
//main.js
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '/js/libs/jquery/jquery.min',
        underscore: '/js/libs/underscore/underscore.min',
        backbone: '/js/libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        bootstrap: '/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        bootstrapDialog: '/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-dialog.min'

    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        bootstrapDialog: {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore","backbone", "bootstrap"]
        }

    }

});
```

And a module example:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrapDialog',
], function($, _, Backbone,  BootstrapDialog){
    console.log("New bootstrap dialog");
    console.log(BootstrapDialog); //BootstrapDialog is always null
});
```

How can I intergrate BootStrapDialog with requireJs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BootstrapDialog registers itself with the name `bootstrap-dialog`, see line 871:

```
define("bootstrap-dialog", function() {
    return BootstrapDialog;
});
```

So you just need to replace `bootstrapDialog` with `'bootstrap-dialog'` in your config.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/znUqvtgLT5rDuUdysgPe?p=preview).